# Rewrite loops in matrix in Python

Tags: python

I have the following piece of code I'd like to optimize:

```
for i in range(img.shape[:2][0]):
    for j in range(img.shape[:2][1]):
        if (img[i, j, 0] < THRESHOLD) and (img[i, j, 2] < THRESHOLD):
            for k in range(3):
              img[i, j, k] = 0
```

It basically loops through the dimensions `x` and `y` of a matrix with shape (H, W, 3), where `H=img.shape[:2][0]` and `W=img.shape[:2][1]`, and checks for every cell if the values of the first and the last layer of the matrix are below a certain threshold, and if so it sets the value for that coordinate equal to zero in the 3 layers.

Is there any shortcut in Python such as:

```
 img[(img[:,:,0]< TRESHOLD) and (img[:,:,2]< TRESHOLD)] = 0` (not working)
```

to run the above loops in a faster way?

Comment: What does *"the following piece of code"* do?

Comment: I don't know what is the type of `matrix` ? but have you tried `&` e.g. : `img[(img[:,:,0]< TRESHOLD) & (img[:,:,2]< TRESHOLD)]` ?

Comment: Having a sample matrix would greatly help understand the question

Comment: Added more information, sorry for that

Comment: if img is a numpy array you can do `img[(img[:,:,0]< TRESHOLD) & (img[:,:,2]< TRESHOLD)] = 0` notice the change from  `and` to  `&`

Comment: Why you want to do that? Reduce 5 lines in 1 line to reduce 0.01KB of script size?? You will get headache on next code revision

Comment: @rotemtal That was it, thanks!!

Comment: @Wonka It's not about size reduction, it's about backing out some parts of a picture